# How to get the first Active Cell when a filter is applied ,without considering the header?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

'Sample Snippet code which i am using

```
Sheets("DRW2ANCMetadata").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:="TRUE" ' Applied filter
Range("A2").Select ' Here A2 can be different value every time based on the excel data example A3 or A100 or A1234
```

Comment: How about `Range("A2").End(xlDown).Select`?

Comment: @Ralph Here A2 can be diffrenet every based on my filter in Sheet1 based on the data. In A1 i have the header.

Comment: @Ralph  i need to get only the first cell below the header , It can be A2 or A3 or A100 or A1234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First non-empty visible cell in the column:

```
Range("A:A").Find("*", Range("A1")).Select
```

First visible cell in the column:

```
Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Range("A1").Select
```

Comment: Hi Mikegrann,The Second one Worked for me .Really thanks for that.But i didnt understand what is use of first one .Can you explain a bit more on that. I am actually new Excel vba scripting

Comment: @SandeepRaghav The first one will automatically skip blank cells. So say A2, A3, and A4 were all visible, but they were all empty. This code will select A5, the first visible, non-empty cell. This could even be used if your data has no empty cells, in which case it will always select the same cell as the second code snippet, while also being faster.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply.Your answer really helped me.